# how to generate qr code with php 7.0 and laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am working on a project which is on laravel 5.5, and I need to generate qr code. for some resign I can't update php version.

I am using https://www.simplesoftware.io/docs/simple-qrcode

but I got error
[image]

how to resolved this issue.

Comment: It's a simple syntax error in your code.  Look closely at the highlighted line.  The message is telling you what to look for.

Comment: Please include your code in the question, not a picture of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a new PHP 7.1 feature called [Nullable types](http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.new-features.php). You probably are on PHP <7.1.

Your question states you cannot upgrade your PHP version ([which you should as versions below 7.2 soon will be depricated](http://php.net/supported-versions.php)). For now you could install an older version of the library. [1.5.1](https://github.com/SimpleSoftwareIO/simple-qrcode/tree/1.5.1) instead of 2.0.0.

> composer require implesoftwareio/simple-qrcode:1.5.1

On second inspection of your exception, the problem seems to lie in Laravel's dependency on [Symfony/Translation](https://github.com/symfony/translation/blob/master/composer.json#L19) using a version of PHP >=7.1.